# How to fix white line below picture

Tags: html, css, image

I have a background image, I have added a png picture (logo) on top of the background picture but I am getting a white line below.

```css
body {
  left: 45%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/468x60?text=Background);
  background-size: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="agtrack" style="text-align: center">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60x60?text=LOGO" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can get images from placeholder.com to use here

Comment: body {
    left: 45%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../Content/PSX_20190124_001950.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}//CSS

Comment: @Ingus here in a stacksnippet like the one I just made is also good

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not need and does not use a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: There seems are nothing wrong. Something that affects your side we do not see.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting the

> display: block;

style on the image. If that doesnt help also try changing the line-height style on your image to either

> line-height: 1;

or

> line-height: 0;

Comment: What is the difference line-height: 0;

or

line-height: 0;?

Comment: I meant "line-height: 1;" sorry. These styles have caught me up in the past and can be easily overlooked. They sometimes leave an extra little margin hanging off your element. @Ingus